# How can I only allow access to my webpage when it is visited by a certain link?

Tags: php, hyperlink, html

I have made an application for android. But I want to place a link to a certain webpage "www.example.com/secret" in this application that allows users to visit this page. I want this webpage not to be visible when it is coming from another website link or if users for example type in "www.example/secret" in there browser. Is this possible without using php password?

Comment: Take a look at "HTTP referer": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer . You might make your Android app pretend to be a particular URL - if you can!

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a session starting in the starting page and then check to see if it exists in the second

Page 1

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['visited'] = "true";
    header("location: second page");
```

Page 2

```
    session_start();
    $visited = @$_SESSION['visited'];
```

And then check to see if $visited is "true"